# Scraping google reviews in maps in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape comments from google maps. Below is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
## Mall of Africa link
url="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mall+of+Africa/@-26.0150912,28.1050221,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x1e956e0fafb856f1:0xeb489d05fbd8c454!8m2!3d-26.0150912!4d28.1072108?hl=en"
html_data = read_html(url)

##Scrape the review comments
get_reviews <- function(x){
  x%>% 
    # The relevant tag
    html_nodes(".section-review-text") %>%      
    html_text()
}


##Output I get
get_reviews(html_data)
character(0)
```

Can someone please be able to assist and possibly point out why this function is not working?

Thanks in advance.